# how to add or push value to array in ionic 3

Tags: arrays, ionic-framework, ionic3, push, addition

How can I add or push value into a array in ionic 3?

my code in .ts

```
optionsArray : Array<{productOptionId : string , productOptionValueId : string}>;
...
checkCheckbox(V,ProductOI,ProductOVI){
if ( V ) {

    this.optionsArray.push({ productOptionId : ProductOI , productOptionValueId : ProductOVI });
  }
```

}

The error message is :

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize your variable first.

```
optionsArray : Array<{productOptionId : string , productOptionValueId : string}> = [];
```